# Error during downloading from maven central repository

Tags: spring, maven, download

I'm trying to make project on Spring. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and during project creation and downloading libs I'm getting this:

> Failed to download 'http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar':
>   Socket is not connected: connect

I'm didn't change settings in IDEA, and when I'm trying to dovnload other libs from maven central - I'm getting same results.
If somebody knows how to solve this problem tell me please.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried hitting that URL in a browser?  Might just be a connection issue from your site to central.

Comment: Yes, I've tried and also when I was trying to download libs 
I had  warning from my brouser about dangerous content

Comment: This problem was solve partly by proxy settings, but I also can't download libs from maven dependencies.